# GCC/Clang doesn't make temporary object

Tags: c++

```
class Sample {
private:
    int         data = 0;
    std::string name = nullptr;

public:
    Sample(int m_data, const std::string& pName) : data(m_data), name(pName) {
        std::cout << "Sample(int, const std::string&): " << name << "\n";
    }

    Sample(const Sample& rhs) : data(rhs.data), name(rhs.name) {
        std::cout << "Sample(const Sample&): " << name << "\n";
    }

    ~Sample() {
        std::cout << "~Sample(): " << name << "\n";
    }
}

Sample TestFunc(int param) {
    Sample a(param, "a");

    return a;
}
```

I've made a class like this and called `TestFunc(20);` in main(). Then following output came out.

```
Sample(int, const std::string&): a
~Sample(): a
```

I expected that a temporary `Sample` object is made so copy constructor should be called, but it wasn't.

This code has compiled with GCC & Clang, and with MSVC, copy constructor is called as I expect.

```
Sample(int, const std::string&): a
Sample(const Sample&): a  // temporary object constructor
~Sample(): a
~Sample(): a  // temporary object destructor
```

What is the problem with GCC/Clang?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization

Comment: FWIW, it should never be a problem if a temporary is not created.  If your code relies on it then it is broken.  Temporaries cost resources so avoiding them is a good thing.

Comment: You're right. I'm just wondering why is it different by compiler.

Comment: With MSVS did you compile is release or debug mode?  With GCC/Clang, what options did you use to compile the code?

Comment: I've set all compilers to debug mode.

Comment: What standard did you compile against?

Comment: CMake option in GCC: `-std=c++14 -m64 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror`